# How to pass Json array to Jenkins shell script

Tags: json, shell, jenkins-pipeline

This is the script :

```
stage('parse') {              
            steps {              
                script{                    
                    sh "cat <<EOF > ${env.WORKSPACE}/src/assets/file4.json \n [{\"name\":\"${name}\",\"apis\":\"[${apis}]\",\"version\":\"${version}\",\"status\":\"${status}\"}] "
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the output in JSON file :

```
[{"name":"Hello","apis":"[dev,qa,prod]","version":"g3","status":"true"}]
```

So the problem in "apis" it's a array! i want to be like this:

```
"apis":["dev","qa","prod"]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting because of this ?

Comment: there is no error , just i want the syntax of apis like array not like string

Comment: Do you really want `"apis":"["dev","qa","prod"]"` or do you want `"apis":"[\"dev\",\"qa\",\"prod\"]"`?

Comment: it's a job with parameters so there is many value apis to select so i want the output in JSON file be like that `"apis":["dev","qa","prod"]`

Comment: Is the question really asking how to write a JSON file with proper formatting from Jenkins Pipeline?

Comment: yes something like that Matt but with the script shell "sh", my problem now is the output of my file json is like that `"apis":"[dev,qa,prod]"` it's string but it should be array for example like that `"apis":["dev","qa","prod"]` because apis have multi-select.